# Capture SSL Certificate Error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

newbie question here I'm afraid... I have looked around and have not found something that has answered my question. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I have looked and not found.

ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'xxx' doesn't match 'xxx'

In short I am trying to catch the ssl mismatch error and printing instead of erroring. As an example, the below:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import ssl
site = 'https://halifaxsharedealing-online.com'
site_request = Request(site)
try:
    response = urlopen(site_request, timeout=10)
except ssl.CertificateError as e:
    print (e)
```

Could someone advise what I'm missing here?

Thanks so much and apologies if I've missed something / if there is an easy thing I've missed.

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: What happens? What is the output you get, instead of the expected one? Your code seems to be working fine when I ran it.

Comment: To clarify, it throws an error. I would like to print the error, but not for it to stop an operation like a loop (say I'm looping through a list of urls, some of which have incorrect SSL certs)

Comment: I modified a little bit your example to have a sort of SSL Error, but I believe the exception raised should be a [URLError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.URLError), so you should actually use in the `except` block something like: `except urllib.error.URLError as e:`